# select_related().prefetch_related() returns invalid field

Tags: django, django-models

There is a class like:

```
class SubCategories(models.Model):
      code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Categories(models.Model):
   subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
         'app.SubCategories',
         related_name='app_category_subcategory'
         )
```

I am going to do a query as follows:

```
Cat = Categories()
Cat.select_related('subcategory').prefetch_related('code').get_or_create(id=2, defaults={ 'subcategory__code':205610})
```

`subcategory_id` works but for `subcategory__code` (which I need) it raises an error that this is invalid field name for `Categories`. That would be nice if someone could tell me how can I access the `code` field from the ForeignKey

Comment: One category can have multiple SubCategories, so you need a way first to get one subcategory or iterate over it..... what do you want to achieve?

Comment: `.prefetch_related('code')` makes no sense: `.prefetch_related(..)` is for relations in reverse. It sill automatically fetch the code of the related object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just removed it.

Comment: @Walucas Should I use kind of filter after select_related()? like `.filter(subcategory__code=205610)`

Comment: To be honest, I dont understand yet what you are trying to do

Comment: @Walucas I am trying to import a csv file to my created models. In created Categories as a joining model because it has two Foriegnkeys however I simplified here to one ForeignKey, so fields call SubCategories and Skills). In my code, I am going to make a loop over CSV first, then make a table of all SubCategories, and then join those created SubCategories into Category to join with another model Foreignkey(Skills)

Comment: So you have two loops, one to load SubCategories, and another for the Categories? Why dont you just fetch the subcategory using filter on the second loop and associate it with the Category during creation?